# How to retry for loop when timeout error occurs: Where to add trycatch or withTimeout

Tags: r, loops

I am running a for loop to try and look through and extract information from my aws s3 account. For some reason when I run the for loop, the loop will stop randomly throughout the loop.  When I say randomly, the loop will stop at different locations each time I run the loop. What I get is an error related to the process timing out. If the loop stopped at the same bucket each time then I would wonder if there was something wrong with the particular bucket. What I noticed is when I manually run commands to list the files in a bucket, sometimes I get a timeout error. If I run the same command, say 3 times, maybe ill get a timeout error 2 of the 3 three times but the 3rd time will go through. I was wondering if I can add maybe a trycatch into my loop or a withTimeout but I am struggling to figure out how to implement them into my for loop. When I try and add them in, it seems like there is still only one attempt before I get a timeout error. Here is the loop I am trying to run

```
files <- NULL
#sample.id <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(sample.id.path2[[1]])){
  a <- as.data.frame(system(paste0("mcli ls s3/path/to/bucket/", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i], sep = ""), intern=TRUE))
  colnames(a)[1] <- "V1"
  a$V1 <- gsub("^.{0,34}", "", a$V1)
  a <- a %>% filter(str_detect(V1, 'fastq'))
  #print(a)
  b <- as.data.frame(paste0("", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i],  sep = ""))
  colnames(b)[1] <- "V1"
  c <- as.data.frame(paste0(b$V1, a$V1,  sep = ""))
  colnames(c)[1] <- "V2"
  d <- cbind(a,c)
  print(d)
  files <- rbind(files, d)
}
```

Here are some examples I have tried to run

```
files <- NULL
#sample.id <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(sample.id.path2[[1]])){
  a <- withTimeout(as.data.frame(system(paste0("mcli ls s3/path/to/bucket/", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i], sep = ""), intern=TRUE)), timeout = 100, cpu = 100, elapsed = 100, onTimeout = "error")
  colnames(a)[1] <- "V1"
  a$V1 <- gsub("^.{0,34}", "", a$V1)
  a <- a %>% filter(str_detect(V1, 'fastq'))
  #print(a)
  b <- as.data.frame(paste0("", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i],  sep = ""))
  colnames(b)[1] <- "V1"
  c <- as.data.frame(paste0(b$V1, a$V1,  sep = ""))
  colnames(c)[1] <- "V2"
  d <- cbind(a,c)
  print(d)
  files <- rbind(files, d)
}
```

and here is another

```
files <- NULL
#sample.id <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(sample.id.path2[[1]])){
  while(TRUE){
  a <- try(as.data.frame(system(paste0("mcli ls s3/path/to/bucket/", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i], sep = ""), intern=TRUE)), silent=TRUE)
  if(!is(df, 'try-error')) break
  colnames(a)[1] <- "V1"
  a$V1 <- gsub("^.{0,34}", "", a$V1)
  a <- a %>% filter(str_detect(V1, 'fastq'))
  }
  #print(a)
  b <- as.data.frame(paste0("", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i],  sep = ""))
  colnames(b)[1] <- "V1"
  c <- as.data.frame(paste0(b$V1, a$V1,  sep = ""))
  colnames(c)[1] <- "V2"
  d <- cbind(a,c)
  print(d)
  files <- rbind(files, d)
}
```

I feel like there is an easy solution to this but I am struggling to figure out where exactly I need to add trycatch or withTimeout into my loop

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to add `until` to the system command? or something along those lines

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Wow.. that is spot on. That fixed the problem. I don't know I missed that. If you want to put that into an answer, I will accept it.. so you can get a little more street cred. I figured out another solution that is more involved with the system command rather than R. I will post that to help anyone else the stumps upon this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but in the third example, using `try()`, you evaluate `if(!is(df, 'try-error'))` but `a` is the object that stores the results of `try()`. So shouldn't it be `if(!is(a, 'try-error'))`

```
files <- NULL
#sample.id <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(sample.id.path2[[1]])){
  while(TRUE){
  a <- try(as.data.frame(system(paste0("mcli ls s3/path/to/bucket/", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i], sep = ""), intern=TRUE)), silent=TRUE)
  if(!is(a, 'try-error')) break
  colnames(a)[1] <- "V1"
  a$V1 <- gsub("^.{0,34}", "", a$V1)
  a <- a %>% filter(str_detect(V1, 'fastq'))
  }
  #print(a)
  b <- as.data.frame(paste0("", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i],  sep = ""))
  colnames(b)[1] <- "V1"
  c <- as.data.frame(paste0(b$V1, a$V1,  sep = ""))
  colnames(c)[1] <- "V2"
  d <- cbind(a,c)
  print(d)
  files <- rbind(files, d)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DaveArmstrong answer works great! I found another solution that doesn't full involve R. I found that the command line tool [retry](https://github.com/kadwanev/retry) works as well with `system()`. I changed my loop to this

```
files <- NULL
#sample.id <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(sample.id.path2[[1]])){
  a <- as.data.frame(system(paste0("retry -t 5 mcli ls s3/path/to/bucket/", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i], sep = ""), intern=TRUE))
  colnames(a)[1] <- "V1"
  a$V1 <- gsub("^.{0,34}", "", a$V1)
  a <- a %>% filter(str_detect(V1, 'fastq'))
  #print(a)
  b <- as.data.frame(paste0("", sample.id.path2[['V2']][i],  sep = ""))
  colnames(b)[1] <- "V1"
  c <- as.data.frame(paste0(b$V1, a$V1,  sep = ""))
  colnames(c)[1] <- "V2"
  d <- cbind(a,c)
  print(d)
  files <- rbind(files, d)
}
```

I added `retry` to the system command and added `-t 5` to retry the command 5 times before timing out